# Preventing random ordering on MYSQL when not using ORDER BY RAND()

Tags: mysql

I am perplexed, because every now and then I am getting a random order just by executing this MySQL command directly on Navicat. In my understanding unless you explicitly use ORDER BY RAND(), the order should be the same all the time, but in this case it's not the case at all.

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts 
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id ) 
INNER JOIN wp_product dg ON dg.post_id = wp_posts.ID 
AND ( dg.location IN ('XV', 'QV', 'DH') ) 
AND (0 OR (dg.srp = 1) OR (dg.SoldDate > (now() - interval 30 DAY) 
AND dg.isPremium = 0 AND dg.SoldDate != '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
AND dg.SoldDate IS NOT NULL AND price > 0 AND NoImage = 0)) 
AND ( dg.deleted IS NULL OR dg.deleted <> 1 ) 
WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_product_info_new' ) 
AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' 
AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish') 
GROUP BY wp_posts.ID 
ORDER BY dg.SoldDate IS NULL, dg.SoldDate ASC, dg.isPremium DESC LIMIT 0, 30
```

wp_product has the same number of rows after executing COUNT(*) for 10 minutes straight. But executing the same query above gives me a different result every 5 seconds or so, which is really strange. Is there a way to prevent the same query from returning a different result set?

Comment: 'ORDER BY dg.SoldDate IS NULL; -never seen this before what was/is your intention.

Comment: Your query is not correct. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY and ensure. *`ORDER BY dg.SoldDate IS NULL, dg.SoldDate ASC, dg.isPremium DESC`* Without these columns or expressions included into GROUP BY expression the value used in the sorting is indefinite, it is indefinitely selected from all existing values in a group. Also the rows for which the ORDER BY expression is the same are ordered indefinitely in a group.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify an ORDER BY, the rows are returned in an undefined order by the SQL standard.

In practice, if you use InnoDB tables, the rows are returned in the order of the index used to access them.

The query optimizer might choose a different index from time to time, depending on the values you search for. It chooses index using a cost-based algorithm, trying to estimate which index will result in examining the fewest rows, or otherwise eliminating overhead.

The estimate is based on statistics about frequency of values in each index, and these are rough estimates, not always precise.

In some cases, the optimizer is choosing between alternatives that it estimates have very close cost according to its algorithm, and very slight changes in the statistics can cause the choice to flip-flop between these alternatives.

The bottom line is that if you need the rows returned in a specific order, then use `ORDER BY`. This will override the default order-by-index-reads behavior, and cause the result to be sorted if necessary.

Comment: If you look at the query the ORDER BY was specified, so it's impossible to have different orders being returned.

Comment: Yes it is, in the case of ties.